# adding seasonality free data to csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I'm new to python and have to write to an exists CSV file the forecast without the seasonality. so I wrote a code handling the matter of seasonality.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose

dateparse = lambda dates: pd.datetime.strptime(dates, '%Y-%m')
data = pd.read_csv('File1.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], index_col='Date', date_parser=dateparse)
ts = data['total_val']
ts_log = np.log(ts)
moving_avg = pd.rolling_mean(ts_log, 12)
decomposition = seasonal_decompose(ts_log)
seasonal = decomposition.seasonal
residual = ts_log - seasonal
```

Now I need to write the results to new column in the same file. 
I've heard that its possible to do so without other files using panda. can anybody help with that?

Comment: Have a look at Lesson 4 of the [Lessons for New pandas Users](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html#lessons-for-new-pandas-users).  You might also want to spend some time with [this Pycon US 2015 talk](http://pandas.pydata.org/talks.html#pycon-us-2015) - It's long but worth it if you plan on using Pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to add a column to a dataframe:

```
data["residual"] = residual
```

to write a csv:

```
data.to_csv("newfile")
```